# Mysql Error: too many connections error

Tags: mysql

I am using windows server and installed mysql on that.
Now its giving me to many connections error.

I did some googeling but tot getting how to resolve the issue.

Please help me on this.

And can anyone explain what is the meaning of

```
max_connections = 151
max_user_connections = 0
```

Comment: See [`max_user_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections): *The maximum number of simultaneous connections permitted to any given MySQL user account. A value of 0 (the default) means “no limit.”*; and [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections): *The maximum permitted number of simultaneous client connections.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `max_connections` limit more than `151`. Login to mysql server as root  and run following commnad

```
set global  max_connections =15000;
```